# Entity Framework Core: Many To Many relationship with some null values for some records

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have the following 3 classes - a `Company` that employs `ConstructionWorkers` and `TruckDrivers`. Let's say those people can be employed at many companies (as they work part time) - so it's a many to many relationship.
Some companies will only employ `TruckDrivers`, others will only employ `ConstructionWorkers` and others yet will employ both. This means in my `CompanyEmployeeMapping` table, the record could look like this:

```
CompanyEmployeeMapping Table:
 
+-------------+------------------+------------------------+
| CompanyId   |   TruckDriverId  |   ConstructionWorkerId | 
+-------------+------------------+------------------------+
|      1      |       10         |         NULL           |  
+-------------+------------------+------------------------+

 (ie - Company only employs Truck Drivers)
```

This is how I set up my Class Structure + Fluent API:

```
 public class Company
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CompanyEmployeeMapping> Employees { get; set; }
 }

 public class ConstructionWorker
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CompanyEmployeeMapping> Companies { get; set; }
 }

 public class TruckDriver
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CompanyEmployeeMapping> Companies { get; set; }
 }

public class CompanyEmployeeMapping
 {
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int TruckDriverId { get; set; }
    public int ConstructionWorkerId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Company LinkedCompany { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public TruckDriver LinkedTruckDriver { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public ConstructionWorker LinkedConstructionWorker { get; set; }
 }
```

Fluent API setup:

```
 builder.Entity<CompanyEmployeeMapping>()
          .HasKey(x => new { x.CompanyId, x.TruckDriverId, x.ConstructionWorkerId });

 builder.Entity<CompanyEmployeeMapping>()
            .HasOne(c => c.LinkedCompany)
            .WithMany(m => m.LinkedEmployees)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CompanyId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Id);

 builder.Entity<CompanyEmployeeMapping>()
            .HasOne(c => c.LinkedTruckDriver)
            .WithMany(m => m.LinkedCompanies)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.TruckDriverId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Id);

 builder.Entity<CompanyEmployeeMapping>()
            .HasOne(c => c.LinkedConstructionWorker)
            .WithMany(m => m.LinkedCompanies)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ConstructionWorkerId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Id);
```

This seems to work correctly for me - I get an object with companies, containing a list of `TruckDrivers` and a list of `ConstructionWorkers`. Each of those also have their corresponding companies.

**QUESTION**

When I try to add a new company, which only employs `TruckDrivers` I get an exception:
`The value of CompanyEmployeeMapping.ConstructionWorkerId is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You might want to overthink your data structure, I suggest you make one general data set employee and link them to a employeeType e.g. Truckdriver, Constructionworker etc.
This way a company just has one set of employees, and you can add as many flavors to employees as you want without creating a mess

Comment: Thanks for this recommendation. It would make sense from the code snippet I provided, but in reality, the properties between TruckDriver and ConstructionWorker are very different from each other to create a common class.

Comment: maybe you can solve this by inheriting from a common baseclass employee so they share a unique employee id pool.

Comment: Yes. This solution should work. However, this still doesn't solve the question of what happens when an entity could map to 2 other separate entities (e.g. A Factory producing Cars and/or Boats). Is the answer to the question to always group the 2 entities to a common base class? Ef Core doesn't allow for an entity to produce a mapping by an ID so long as that ID is present for at least 1 of the 2 entities?

Comment: Yes I'd always go for a baseclass that contains the id and common attributes, because you will have problems like yours and it becomes worse if there are more than 2 involved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each instance of the mapping entity will only map to either TruckDriver or ConstructionWorker.

Therefore, your TruckDriver and ConstructionWorker ids need to be nullable.

This will then create a new challenge that your composite key cannot contain a nullable property.

I think the way forward is to make those ints nullable and then create a new single property EmployeeMapping Id for the mapping entity key.